# How to remove specific last two lines of a file?

Tags: python, replace

I need to remove the following last two lines from my textfile:

```
ColorForeground=#000000
ColorBackground=#ffffff
```

The above lines are appended to the `terminalrc` file with the following command:

```
echo -e "ColorForeground=#000000\nColorBackground=#ffffff">>/home/jerzy/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
```

Thus, the last lines of the file to be modified look like this

```
DropdownKeepOpenDefault=TRUE
ColorForeground=#000000
ColorBackground=#ffffff
```

I wrote the following Python script in order to remove the last two lines of the file with `.replace()` method:

```
day = r"ColorForeground=#000000\nColorBackground=#ffffff"

file = r"/home/jerzy/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc"

with open(file) as f:
    content = f.read()
    content = content.replace(day, "")
    with open(file, 'r+') as f2:
        f2.write(content)
```

Yet, my script does not work as expected. The following is the result of its execution:

```
DropdownKeepOpenDefault=TRUE

olorForeground=#000000
ColorBackground=#ffffff
```

Where is the error in my Python code? How would you write such a script? Is this task doable without using regular expressions?

Comment: don't read the last two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read and write seperately, also don't make `day` a raw string, that will escape the newline-

```py
day = "ColorForeground=#000000\nColorBackground=#ffffff\n"

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

content = content.replace(day, "")

with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```